# The required attribute 'Id' is missing

Tags: c#, exception, exchangewebservices

I get the following exception error trying to load a file-attachment into memory when using the .load() function.

> **The required attribute 'Id' is missing**

I cannot explicitly assign the Id property because it is readonly. Any ideas?

```
EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(Exchange);
email.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("picture.jpg");
email.Attachments[0].IsInline = true;
email.Attachments[0].ContentId = "picture.jpg";
email.Attachments[0].Load(); // Errors here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Load() method loads the attachment by making an EWS call. From your code snippet, it is bound to fail as the email object has not been created yet in Exchange, so it does not have an Id to refer to. (ref: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.attachment.load(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.attachment.load%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx))

Can you give a little more background to the problem that you are trying to solve?
From an above comment, you mentioned being able to Attach an email to another parent email. You might be interested to take a look at adding ItemAttachments in the link @JPRO provided above. 
Also refer to AttachmentCollection Class: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.attachmentcollection_methods(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.attachmentcollection_methods%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

Again, as I don't know the problem you are trying to solve, these may or may not be useful to you. It would be helpful if you could give a little more context.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to use Load? Based on [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633668%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) I believe you can attach a jpg like this:

```
EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(Exchange);
byte[] picBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"path\to\picture.jpg");
email.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("picture.jpg", picBytes);
email.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Comment: The jpg was just an example... it's actually an xml file. In the bigger picture, I would like to add the email to another email (emailParent) as an attachment and send that. But there no function where I can do something like: emailParent.Attachments.Add(email). Add() is not an option. Suggestions?

Comment: When you say add email to another email I assume you don't mean forwarding the original. In that case there are two options. Options one you save the email somewhere as a file then use AddFileAttachment as in the above answer. Option 2 you look into converting the child email object into a stream which you can then call parentEmail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, contentType)

Answer (score 0):

ID is set internally, is it possible the file you specified doesn't exist in the execution directory?

Have you tried loading it in as a stream instead? ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634477(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634477%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx))

Comment: The file does exist as when I call email.SendAndSaveCopy() the file is in the email in my Outlook inbox. I have tried adding in the byte stream but this still does not set the ID internally...